# How to auto refresh page without a plugin?

Tags: html

I'm looking to take a website (employees' schedule) and put it on a big screen so that people can see the live schedule at any point in time. We need this website to auto refresh every 15-30 minutes, but we can NOT utilize a plugin/extension.

Does anyone have ideas through on how to change either the URL or the developer tools to write something to have it auto refresh?

Comment: what os? what software is employed on your website?

Comment: Can you modify the HTML of the web page?

Answer (score 5):

You can do in multiple ways like using meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900"/>
```

The browser will then refresh the page every 15 minutes.

You don't need any plugin for that. You can use simple javascript :

```
setTimeout(function() {
  location.reload();
}, 900000);
```

Otherwise, if you don't need to refresh the whole page but only a part of it, I guess an Ajax call would be the most efficient way.

Comment: This was the original route that I went, Developer Tools-> "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/> using 10 just as a test example. The problem that I had here was that it would refresh and then wipe out the <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>, so it was only refreshing once.

Comment: If you want to prevent the page from being cached there's this: 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

Comment: you can try JS code now all browser supports js

Comment: When you use the meta tag, the page refreshes, but then the new, refreshed version of the page does not have the meta tag anymore. How does one keep the meta tag in the HTML?